# 404 Error after Bundling Aurelia Application for Production

Tags: aurelia

I have just finished creating my first Aurelia App and I wish to export it to a production server. I have read lots of helpful tutorials about how to bundle and export an Aurelia App and I can say I am close to the end. I have successfully bundled and exported my App (to the [app-folder]/[export-folder]) with all dependencies (i.e config.js, jspm, dist) without any errors. However, when I run the app I get the following error:

```
system.js:4 GET [app-folder]/[export-folder]/bootstrap-form-validation-renderer.js 404 (Not Found)
```

To explain, my app has a form that makes use of the new Aurelia Validation Libraries i.e aurelia-validate and aurelia-validatejs. One of the requirements is to define how validation errors are rendered and I successfully implemented this by having this code in my main.js

```
 export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging()
    .plugin('aurelia-validation')
    .plugin('aurelia-validatejs')
    .feature('bootstrap-validation');

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

And then, in my [app-folder]/src I have a bunch of files including:

```
[app-folder]/src/bootstrap-validation
[app-folder]/src/bootstrap-validation/index.js
[app-folder]/src/bootstrap-validation/bootstrap-form-validation-renderer.js
```

I can run the app just fine when using gulp watch (localhost:9000) without any error but the error comes once I bundle and export. Is the feature/file not getting included anywhere? Am I missing something in the bundles/export js files? I appreciate any help towards solving this. Thank you for your time!

PS: If it helps, I am using a PC running Windows 10.

Comment: you might have to include your files in the build/bundles.js

Comment: Exactly what I thought. But I am a bit confused as to what path to use. Should i use 'bootstrap-validation' or 'src/bootstrap-validation'?

Comment: try "aurelia-validation", "aurelia-validatejs", "bootstrap-validation"

Comment: Got an error during build. Says it can't find the specified resource in the dist/ folder. Yet it's there.

Comment: remove bootstrap-validation from bundles.js, but keep aurelia-validation and aurelia-validatejs. Tell me what happens now

Comment: Oh. Now I get a different error. The app runs well except for the following error I get in the console: `system.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) Error: http://localhost/app/export/bootstrap-form-validation-renderer.js: Unexpected token (4:0)`

Comment: What you have in line 4?

Comment: Here is the code: [link](http://pastebin.com/PcdVEMce)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116699/discussion-between-realnsleo-and-fabio-luz).